Some confusion about articles
I am a new member, and today I came across a paragraph that has some usages of articles that make me confuse. Can you guys help me explain why is "the" used in these places?
Here is the paragraph:

Assemble our organizers in a room and you’d find Italians from Philly, Jews from Chicago; children of poor immigrants and children of the rich suburbs. There seemed no way to connect their wildly varied experiences to the meat-and-potatoes folks whose votes we desperately needed. And yet they did connect. Arriving in town with a duffel bag or a small suitcase, living in the spare bedroom or basement of some early local supporter, they would spend months getting to know a place—visiting the local barbershop, setting up card tables in front of the grocery store, speaking at the Rotary Club. They helped coach Little League, assisted local charities, and called their moms for a banana pudding recipe so they wouldn’t show up to the potluck empty-handed.


You have "some confusion".  Confuse is a verb, and confusion is a noun.

Not every single cultura usage is found in grammar books. Listen to native speakers re US culture, like TimR.

This paragraph is from Barack Obama's memoir A Promised Land, which explores his early life, political career, presidential campaign, and first term in office.
In this passage, Obama describes political organizers who travel to small towns to help with campaigns.
The paragraph shows how these organizers live simply, often staying with local supporters and engaging with the community through everyday activities:

"the local barber shop" a typical part of small-town life.
"the grocery store": specific to the community.
"the Rotary Club": a known institution in the town.
"the potluck": a familiar community event.

In each case, the definite article "the" indicates these are not just general places or things, but specific, meaningful elements of small-town life. Obama uses "the" to make these places feel familiar, highlighting how the organizers connect with the community.

Thank you guys very much, by the way, I have another question also related to this topic. Is it right if I use the non-definite article here or use the plural form like:
Ex: Visiting a local barbershop, setting up a card table in front of a grocery store, speaking at a Rotary Club.
or
Ex: Visiting local barbershops, setting up card tables in front of grocery stores, speaking at Rotary Clubs.

When you say "the barber shop" or "the grocery store," it generally implies one of these two things:

A specific barbershop or grocery store you regularly visit: Using "the" here signals that it’s a familiar place you often go to.
The only barbershop or grocery store in the area: If there’s only one barbershop or grocery store in the locality, "the" indicates that both you and your listener would know which one you mean, as it’s unique to that area.
Otherwise use a barber shop, a grocery store. If you visit multiple places use plural.


When referring to generic places  or organizations or activities -- things that every small town typically has -- we use the definite article:  the local barber-shop, the grocery store, the Rotary Club, the potluck.  Everyone will recognize such things as typical and commonplace, even stereotypical, and the definite article presents them as such.

She looked the part of the stereotypical diner waitress from the 1950s,  down to the beehive hair-do.

Why is the licensed there?  Because the definite article expresses that such a hair-do is part of the stereotype.
Stereotypes are familiar and recognizable.

Thank TimR, but I wonder where this rule comes from. Because I do not find them in any English grammar books. Please pardon me if I'm rude about this question.

See this website - the second section "because there is only one in that context".

@TrieuHo Where it "comes from"?  The rule is not issued by anyone. The rule is  a description of a particular use of the definite article that one encounters in the speech of native speakers.

Gosh, so tiring when a native speaker provides usage and then gets dv-ed. It really annoys me especially two downvotes like this.

@Lambie I'm probably not using the right magic words.

Yeah and it happens to me all the time.

@ishtar   Familiarity is involved, true, and  the specific cultural element is the cultural stereotype.  It's generic in the sense of "cookie-cutter":  every small town over a certain size has a chapter of the Rotary Club, for example, and  church potlucks are going on all over the country by the thousands.  It's like saying in the 1930s, "The family was sitting by the radio."   The stereotypical American household had a radio and the stereotypical family listened to it together in the evening.
